# Gradle and webpack --watch

Tags: gradle, webpack

I have a frontend subproject, which build css and js bundles via `com.moowork.node` plugin. It runs `npm run dev` under the hood, and my bundles appears. `npm run dev` calls webpack with some options.

Also I have a spring boot subproject, which started via gradle `bootRun` task. Spring dev tools included in dependencies.

And last, I run `gradlew build -x test --continuous` in root of my projects. After changing something, gradle build starts and builds all projects if needed: frontend first, then spring boot app. Spring dev tools see the changes in classpath and app reloads.

All works fine, except one problem: frontend builds every time as first time, and it is really slow. To fix it I need to run webpack with `--watch` option. And do some other frontend build improvements, which need to `--watch` option to webpack too.

But if I add `--watch` option to webpack, `gradlew build -x test --continuous` will never ends, because webpack now never ends. And build of my spring boot app never happens.

How to run webpack `--watch` in `--continuous` build in gradle?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this in a reasonable way? I got stuck on the same problem and am leaning toward just running my build and webpack separately.

Comment: I do same thing - run watching webpack separately. I don't know how to do this with only gradle

Comment: @AlexT Were you able to find a solution for this or do you still run it separately? and how exactly do you do it separately, you build the frontend with gradle using webpack without --watch, and then you run a separate webpack --watch?

Comment: Hi! That project is finished about half year ago. I don't find solution, and run it separately. May be it exists for now, I don't know